# Not able to retrieve value returned by parameterzied method in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, parameter-passing

I have to put parameter in method defined in bean as.The parameters are static.I did this in jsp page as-

```
<%
String n= "p49_readback";
ref.getDbTable(n);
%>
```

Through this I'm getting value in java  bean method and the method is

```
public String getDbTable(String parameter)
        {
     String  tolerance =null;
      LinkedHashMap<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();//Holds the beamline name and status  
      try
                { 
                  con = getConnection();
                  stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
                  String sql="select Tolerance from Reference.dbo.Set_range where Parameter_Name='"+parameter+"'";
                  System.out.println("sql "+sql);
                  stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                  rs = stmt.getResultSet();

                  while(rs.next()) 
                  {
                     tolerance= (rs.getString(1));
                     System.out.println("value of tolerance is "+tolerance);

                  }
                }
             catch( Exception e )
            {
                System.out.println("\nException in getDbTable "+e);
            }
            finally
            {
                closeConnection(stmt, rs, con);
            }
            return tolerance;
```

Now I want to call this method in jsp and store its value into a variable.But I'm not able to retrieve or call this method in jsp page .
I tried as

```
  <c:set value="${ref.getDbTable(param.p49_readback)}" var="db"></c:set>
```

But its a wrong approach,I'm not getting value returned by the method.How to do that?

Comment: I personally would recommend not to do any logic in JSPs (such as connecting to a database) apart from displaying things. Are you using plain JSPs or a framework such as Spring MVC?

Comment: @Bret,I'm using palin jsp,no framework.I'm not connecting Database through Jsp.I need to call this getDbTable() in JSP which I'm not able to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using plain JSPs, you could just do this...

```
<%
    String n= "p49_readback";
    String reference = ref.getDbTable(n);
%>
```

Now anywhere you want to use this, just do...

```
<%=reference%>
```

You could even do...

```
<%
    String n= "p49_readback";
    String reference = ref.getDbTable(n);
%>
<c:set var="reference" value="<%=reference%>"/>
```

Comment: I want to compare the value returned by grtDbtable(n) through the following jsp code  <td style="${r.p49_dacbyadc-row.p49_dacbyadc le<%=rederence%>? 'background-color: lime':'background-color: pink'}">. Is this the way?

Comment: But I can't write <%=reference%> in ${}.So what to do?

Comment: @tiddirastogi If you have used the "c:set" construct mentioned above, I think you should just be able to refer to it as ${reference} (it's been a while since I did any JSP work...)